# awk comaprsion with conditions

Tags: awk, conditional-statements

I have question about printing of rows, which have same 4th column, but different 1st column.

INPUT:

```
156817  GJB2    HET 882745
156817  ASPA    HET 882745
156817  HFE HET 882745
156917  ABCA4   HET 882745
156917  MEFV    HET 882745
156917  HFE HET 882745
228417  GJB2    HET 883590
228417  BTD HET 883590
228417  MCCC1   HET 883590
```

OUTPUT:

```
156817  HFE HET 882745 156917   HFE HET 882745
```

For understand: 
I would like to get results only for 1st columns, which are different, but have same 4th column and have same 2nd column and print it to one row. So for this example. There is Same 4th column (882745), but different 1st column (156817 and 156917) and have same 2nd column (HFE). This is really hard for me to do that. I tried so many ways, but I can get the result. 
Thank you

What I did try:

```
awk -F'\t' -v OFS="\t" '{prev=$0; f1=$2; f2=$4; f3=$1
getline
if ($2 == f1 && $4 == f2 && $1!= f3 ) {
print prev
print }
}' file
```

But it doesn't work..

Comment: We're best able to help you when you include your best attempt (in code) to solve your problem. Please update your Q and people will help clarify your understanding of how `awk` works (or point you to other, more appropriate tools). Good luck.

Comment: AND, do you really want your output on one line?

Comment: It is not necessary to get result in one line.. Yes I wrote a code to main question..But I am not proud on this code....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

```
awk -F'\t' '{ k=$2 SUBSEP $3 SUBSEP $4 }
            { if((k in a) && $1!=a[k]){ printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s ", a[k],$2,$3,$4,$0 }
            else a[k]=$1 }END{ print "" }' file
```

The output:

```
156817  HFE HET 882745  156917  HFE HET 882745
```